# No python found at C:\Users\MY HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe

Tags: javascript, python, css, reactjs, web

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/19fmDSI59xoHFoviJyJwciRfI9vZXFEcw/view?usp=sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmd1s.png)
I want to run a react js application but not able to start it due to the following error C:\Users\MY HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe How can I rectify it. I try uninstalling the node modules, I think it might be due to some chane in the environmental variables

Comment: It says It's not able to find the python environment variable, try re-installing and also set the python path in windows environment variable manually this time and try again.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HcGnmdCp62N27Jv7Ap_-0zf-di46M-k8/view?usp=sharing    I already have all the paths here

Comment: Reset the path and restart your system once.